# I want to monitoring files which are processing in last an hour

Tags: shell-script

I have few requirement please help

I want to monitoring files which are processing in last an hour in specific directory.

1. How many files arrived in last one hour?
2. How many file processed in last one hour(Please note my process
   delete file after processing)?
3. Which one is last unprocessed file

Comment: What do you mean with "processed"? New files? Modified files (written to)? Accessed files (read from)? There are a bunch of options for something like this, depending on what the requirements are.

Comment: New files which received into the particular directory

Comment: In the last hour, or where processes last an hour? Please fix the ambiguity in your question title.

Comment: If you delete files after processing then aren't all files in category 3? What is the last unprocessed file otherwise? And if processed means "New files which received into the particular directory" then what's the difference between category 1 and 2?  This is a very unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

To look for existing files, `find` is probably the most useful.

If you know the files are new, looking at the ctime should be enough. 
This would look for files with ctime less than 60 minutes in the past.

```
find . -cmin -60
```

If you want to include older files that were modified, use `find . -mmin -60 -o -cmin -60` to also check the modification timestamp.

If, instead, you want to see the files as they are created (or modified, or deleted), `inotifywait` can help there. This would print a line for each file created or deleted as long as the program runs. `timeout` from GNU coreutils could be used to limit how long it runs.

```
inotifywait -q -m -e create,delete  .
```